# Connecting an Api to a Unity project on WebGl (SmarterAsp.net)

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, webgl

So I've been trying to connect a Unity project with an API and build it on WebGl platform.
On Android, Windows App and WebGl IN Unity, it works fine, but when I build it on the WebGl platform it doesn't work.
Check the API link below for testing:
http://syriatech07-001-site1.htempurl.com/Users

The solution I've found but I didn't know how to apply it was to add a **HOST** to the headers.
I've tried this API "https://httpbin.org/get" and it worked very fine.
If any additional information needed please let me know.

Edit: 
Here's the connection code:

```
IEnumerator GetDataCoroutineASync()
{
    // Showing the result
    outPutArea.text = "Loading.....";

    string uri = "http://syriatech07-001-site1.htempurl.com/Users";
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        request.SetRequestHeader("Host", "syriatech07-001-site1.htempurl.com");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization,Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token,Accept, X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        var op = request.SendWebRequest();

        yield return op;

        if (request.isNetworkError)
        { outPutArea.text = "isNetworkError"; }
        else if (request.isHttpError)
        { outPutArea.text = "isHttpError"; }
        else
        { outPutArea.text = request.downloadHandler.text; }
    }
}
```

`Access to fetch at 'http://syriatech07-001-site1.htempurl.com/Users' from origin 'http://localhost:64929' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. syriatech07-001-site1.htempurl.com/Users:1  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: Please provide sample code to reproduce - but more importantly showing what you tried as adding headers and cors is well documented

Comment: @BugFinder i have updated the quation. you can check the code snippet now

Comment: Is the server you are calling one you can control or request changes on?

Comment: I built the API app on asp.net core (minimal API).
The server is under my control, I'm using SmarterASP.net servers.

Comment: Well cors if you read on it is easiest controlled from the server not your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using asp core minimal API, add this to your web.config and it'll work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In addition, delete all the headers you have added.

> request.SetRequestHeader

Check this [link](https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1980/fix-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource.aspx) from SmarterAsp for more information

Comment: thank you, i have been working on it for 2 days.